# Filter using project activity codes dissapper during copy in Primavera P6

Tags: primavera

I'm working on Primare P6 R8.4. I need to copy a project to work on a new scenario. When I do this activity filters using project activity codes dissapper in new copy. I need a walkaround to overcome this stiuation.

I know I can use EPS activity codes but those have problem with in XER exports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, when you copy the project, the filters will become empty. To keep the filters from clearing out when you copy the project, it's best to use Global Activity Codes. Even EPS Activity Codes may give you issues.

The only problem is with import / export - those activity codes will be exported and imported into someone else's database - even if they didn't want them.

An 2nd alternative is to avoid Activity Codes, and use User Defined Fields (UDF) instead. The filters will endure if you build them around UDFs.

Answer (score 1):

The UDF is the same like activity codes.. it just disappears from the filters. I just tried making activity codes and filters global and the layouts are copied with the filters associated.Phew

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use WS/API from EPPM